# How to fix compatibility issues with Gradle plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.android? "The Gradle plugin, with its Kotlin grace, Encounters clashes"

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Kotlin and Gradle and I have this buildgradle app code:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.20"
}


android {
    namespace 'com.example.loginregisterapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.loginregisterapp"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
}type here
```

And this is my build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

    }

    dependencies {
        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

}

task clean (type: Delete){
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the problem I'm getting:

```
Build file 'C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\loginregisterapp\app\build.gradle' line: 4

Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.8.20']
> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the following error:

> Build file 'C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\loginregisterapp\app\build.gradle' line: 4

Because you have specified the version for Kotlin in the following line of code:

```
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.20"
```

Inside your build.gradle (Module:app) file. There is no need to specify that inside `plugins` since you already did that inside build.gradle (Project) file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
    ...
}
```

If you want to define the variable for Kotlin inside the build.gradle (Project) then you don't need to do that also in the other file. So to solve this, simply remove the version and the error will go away:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' //Removed the version
}
```

Comment: Hy there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?